# Swift Address Book, iterating on emails gets errorType

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

**Xcode 6.4**
**Swift 1.2**

I'm trying to iterate on user contacts, and for each contact that have emails, iterate on the emails.
The problem is, I'm getting the email as errorType when converting it to string instead of getting it as a String object.

My question is, why is this happening?
Why is EmailID not recognized as *String*?

This is my code:

```
let allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(self.addressBookRef).takeRetainedValue() as Array

for record in allContacts
{

    let currentContact: ABRecordRef = record;

    let emailMultiValue:ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(currentContact, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef

    if ABMultiValueGetCount(emailMultiValue) > 0 {
        let emailAddresses: NSArray = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailMultiValue).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray

        for email :AnyObject in emailAddresses {
            if let emailID = email as? String{
                //EmailID is <<errorType>>
                println(emailID) //actually prints the email

            }

        }
    }

}
```

[image]

edit:
I tried to replace emailAddressed with that line.

```
let emailAddresses: [String] = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailMultiValue).takeUnretainedValue() as! [String]
```

But still, I get the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: `emailAdresses` is supposed to be an array of `String`. This works on my machine `for email in emailAddresses as! [String] { println(email) }`

Comment: hey thanks, as you can see in my code, I wrote that println(email) actually prints the email, problem is xCode recognizes it as errorType and not as String

Comment: On my machine it's recognized correctly, I'm using also the `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion()` dance to get access to the address book

Comment: Yea this is the callback function for the request access, and i'm also getting firstname and lastname and it works fine and recognizes it as a string  `ABRecordCopyValue(currentContact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this is solved by iterating on indexes and not on elements

```
for i in 0..<emailAddresses.count {
    let email:String = emailAddresses[i]; //email is actually a string now
}
```

if anyone knows anyway why iterating elements produce error type i'd really like to know